# Please help me to understand this codility test

Tags: java, algorithm

Given the codility test below:

> Given an array `A` of `N` integers, we draw `N` discs in a 2D plane such that the `I`-th
>   disc is centered on `(0,I)` and has a radius of `A[I]`. We say that the `J`-th disc and
>   K`-th disc intersect if`J ≠ K`and`J`-th and`K`-th discs have at least one common
>   point.
>
> Write a function `class Solution { public int solution(int[] A); }` that, given an array
>   `A` describing `N` discs as explained above, returns the number of pairs of intersecting
>   discs. For example, given `N=6` and:
>
> `A[0] = 1  A[1] = 5  A[2] = 2`
>      `A[3] = 1  A[4] = 4  A[5] = 0`
>
> Intersecting discs appear in **eleven pairs of elements**:
>
> 0 and 1,
>      0 and 2,
>      0 and 4,
>      1 and 2,
>      1 and 3,
>      1 and 4,
>      1 and 5,
>      2 and 3,
>      2 and 4,
>      3 and 4,
>      4 and 5.
>
> so the function should return `11`.
>
> The function should return `−1` if the number of intersecting pairs exceeds 10,000,000.
>   Assume that:
>
> -`N`is an integer within the range `[0..100,000]`;
>   - Each element of array A is an integer within the range [0..2147483647].
>
> **Complexity**
>
> - Expected worst-case time complexity is O(N*log(N));
> - Expected worst-case space complexity is O(N), beyond input storage (not counting the
>     storage required for input arguments).

Where do these eleven pairs come from, since there are only 6 elements?

Comment: The pairs come from selecting among the 30 possible combinations of two elements, using the rule given.

Comment: I believe we need to consider combination and not the permutation here. So, The pairs come from selecting among the 15 possible combinations of two elements in `C(n,r)=C(6,2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are only 6 elements, but the number of possible pairs is `6*5/2=15` (general form: `n(n-1)/2)`), so even though there are 6 points, there could be up to 15 (inclusive) intersections, as described above.

The number of disks is not the maximal 15, because some 'disks' do not intersect, for example, the disk `(0,0)` and disk `(0,5)` has no common point. `(0,0)` include the points `{(0,0), (0,1)}` and the `(0,5)` disk include the point `{ (0,5) }`.

Since the intersection of these 2 sets is empty - `(0,0);(0,5)` is not a valid pair of disks, and should not be included.

Comment: Very helpful explanation

Answer (score 1):

The eleven pairs are exactly as listed in the question. Each disc is centred on `(0, I)`, so each disc is 1 distance unit from each of its two neighbours (except for disc 0 and disc N-1, which only have one neighbour). With the particular array A given:

- disc 0 has radius 1, so it intersects with disc 1
- disc 1 has radius 5, so it intersects with discs 0, 2, 3, 4, 5
- disc 2 has radius 2, so it intersects with discs 0, 1, 3, 4
- disc 3 has radius 1, so it intersects with discs 2, 4
- disc 4 has radius 4, so it intersects with discs 0, 1, 2, 3, 5
- disc 5 has radius 0, so it intersects with no discs

If you only count unique pairs from this list (e.g. 2 intersects with 3 and 3 intersects with 2, which counts as one), this comes to 11 intersections.